# Uploading files using multipart form to Shopify files using Fastify multi-part

Tags: node.js, form-data, shopify-app, fastify, fastify-multipart

I'm using Fastify-multipart v5.3.1 with fastify v3 (for compatibility reasons) I use it to upload files from the client to the server and then from the server to Shopify.

From client to our server the files are transferred correctly but I'm having trouble with making a fetch call and appending the files to the formData (see the screenshot using fastify multipart). It throws an error in regards to not using a Blob.
In my old approach (without using fastify) It seems that   files[i].data holds the Buffer data which might be of type File which is allowed in the append method, but with Fastify I'm having trouble because the structure of the variable of files returned from .saveRequestFiles or when using parts is different.

I have been struggling with this issue for a while now and I'd appreciate the help.

Note: To understand exactly what I'm trying to do please check this doc on uploading files to Shopify:
https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/online-store/media/products#step-2-add-media-to-a-product

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Reading [the docs](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-multipart/tree/v5.3.1#upload-files-to-disk-and-work-with-temporary-file-paths) `files[i].file` does not exist.
- Reading [the code](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-multipart/blob/8f8e37b3277064ac2734bf8edb9a0a14d556acee/index.js#L493), `files[i].file` is a consumed readable stream, so you can't access it anymore

So if the `saveRequestFiles()` is used, it is needed to read the `files[i].filepath` to create a new Readable stream.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying that but I'm not sure if it works or not, Is the following correct?

 const files = await request.saveRequestFiles();

    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(files[0].filepath); //NEW
    const fileName = files[0].filename;
    const filePath = files[0].filepath;
  

    formData.append('file', fileStream, fileName );

Comment: It is not optimal (because the file is stored in the FS and then read it back), but it should work. The best option would be to manage the input stream instead (here some basic info: https://backend.cafe/fastify-multipart-upload )

Comment: So If I try something like this:
  const storedFile = fs.createWriteStream(`./${part.filename}`);

Then i should pass the storedFile like this?
 formData.append('file', storedFile, fileName );

Won't this store the file on disk and I'd have to manually remove it? I use saveRequestFiles() because it will automatically remove the temporary file.